# Audio Video (ogg) Generation using Javascript

Tags: javascript, video, ogg

is it possible to generate/send video/audio using javascript ??

for example, see jspdf - http://jspdf.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/examples/basic.htm generate client side generated pdf file using base64 encoded datauri and embed the datauri !

Can similar approach be applied for generation of Ogg files ?

This can be useful for text to speech in browser.

Comment: I'm working on recording straight to ogg my self, I have it working straight to mp3 but my company rightfully has licensing concerns with MP3 so I'm looking at ogg/speex, I'll let you know if I get it working.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that wave/PCM is supported as an audio format by all browsers that support the media elements, so it should be relatively trivial to generate a data url for a pcm file.

Video is more difficult -- there isn't a standard codec for video, and possibly more importantly i doubt any js engine is fast enough yet to generate encoded video sufficiently quickly (given that native implementations have only relatively recently gotten to > realtime performance)

Comment: This depends on the dimensions, of course. Maybe it would be possible to use canvas to generate **small** videos (resolution-wise). However, we have that sluggish thing some call a *"web browser"*. Macro$hit Idiot Exploiter is not going away soon.

Answer (score 1):

You can embed video and audio data in [data URIs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data:_URI_scheme#Examples)

themaninblue has made a [javascript drum machine](http://www.themaninblue.com/experiment/JS-909/)

have a look at the [source code](http://www.themaninblue.com/experiment/JS-909/js/main.js) as an example

Answer (score 1):

Slightly offtopic, but if what you need is text to speech, [you could split the text into chunks of up to 100 characters and use Google Translate TTS.](http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?q=you+could+split+the+text+into+chunks+of+up+to+100+characters+and+use+Google+Translate+TTS.)

Answer (score 0):

I just checked out Audiolet https://github.com/oampo/Audiolet - it's pretty slick